# Modify an array of objects with for in

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format a date inside an object.

I'm currently have the next array of objects:

```
    [
      { date: 2022-01-03T05:00:41.560Z },
      { date: 2022-01-03T22:54:33.980Z },
      { date: 2022-01-03T22:50:26.920Z },
      { date: 2022-01-03T22:32:29.660Z },
      { date: 2022-01-03T22:22:58.480Z }
    ]
```

And I'm trying to do the next:

```
    for (const prop in obj) {
        obj[prop].date = moment(obj[prop].date).tz("America/Vancouver").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }
```

Expecting:

```
    [
      { date: 2022-01-02 },
      { date: 2022-01-03 },
      { date: 2022-01-03 },
      { date: 2022-01-03 },
      { date: 2022-01-03 }
    ]
```

But I can't

```js
let obj = [
{ date: "2022-01-03T05:00:41.560Z" },
{ date: "2022-01-03T22:54:33.980Z" },
{ date: "2022-01-03T22:50:26.920Z" },
{ date: "2022-01-03T22:32:29.660Z" },
{ date: "2022-01-03T22:22:58.480Z" }
];
for (const prop in obj) {
  obj[prop].date = moment(obj[prop].date).tz("America/Vancouver").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-42PE0rd+wZ2hNXftlM78BSehIGzezNeQuzihiBCvUEB3CVxHvsShF86wBWwQORNxNINlBPuq7rG4WWhNiTVHFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

modify it, I keep getting the original array

Comment: Your data is an array of objects so you probably want [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) instead: `for (const obj of data) {...}`.

Comment: The code,as is in your example, seems to work fine (*see https://jsfiddle.net/cdysmvf3/). Perhaps your data is coming from an immutable source and so you cannot modify them. Where do you get the `obj` from ?

Comment: Please update the snippet to a [mcve] - I could not find the correct moment from cdn to help you

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli I'm getting it from a db.collection.find().then(()=>{})

Comment: I wonder if the problem is due to moment-timezone installation not having the Vancouver data.  With plain old moment, and `.utcOffset('-7:00')`, (and a little syntax cleanup) I see your code working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use Array.map for this transformation:

```
const data = [
  { date: '2022-01-03T05:00:41.560Z' },
  { date: '2022-01-03T22:54:33.980Z' },
  { date: '2022-01-03T22:50:26.920Z' },
  { date: '2022-01-03T22:32:29.660Z' },
  { date: '2022-01-03T22:22:58.480Z' }
];

const res = data.map(
  ({ date }) => ({
    date: moment(date).tz("America/Vancouver").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  })
);

console.log(res);
```

in this example we are deconstructing each object and only extracting `date`, and return a new object that's only got `date` in it

Taking below comments into account, try Array.forEach:

```
data.forEach(
  ({ date }, index) => {
    data[index].date = moment(date).tz("America/Vancouver").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't modify `data` which the OP seems to want

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's the OP snippet running, improved slightly by using for-of, and (not sure if this is an improvement or a work-around) by using the native timezone offset.

```js
let data = [
  { date: "2022-01-03T05:00:41.560Z" },
  { date: "2022-01-03T22:54:33.980Z" },
  { date: "2022-01-03T22:50:26.920Z" },
  { date: "2022-01-03T22:32:29.660Z" },
  { date: "2022-01-03T22:22:58.480Z" }
];

for (const obj of data) {
  obj.date = moment(obj.date).utcOffset('-7:00').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```